# Check for the server name in connection string if it exists or not

Tags: vb.net, string, connection

I have done a program where in which I'll pass the server name to the connection string at run time. I need to check if the server name is valid.

Help me out with this?

Comment: Valid in what way? That the machine exists? That the machine is a database server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check server connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364978/how-to-check-server-connection)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources() method to get a list of available SQL servers. (see MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.getdatasources.aspx)

You alternatively might want to connect to the server in a Try..Catch block and check if the connection status is 'open'.